# Keybord events do not work properly

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have created a game which works fine but I have a problem with the key commands part. When I click somewhere on the screen my KeyDown event does not work. I guessed that the control which has the event handler for KeyDown loses the focus and my application was not getting the message. I have spent one week trying to solve the problem.

I tried to set the KeyDown event for more controls. I also tried to set the focus of the control which handles the events without success.

I would appreciate if someone tell me what is the right way of handling the key press collection in my game which will work whatever happens in my application. I just want to know when the user pressed the arrow keys in order to change the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, but I then hooked into how they do it in LayoutAwarePage.CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated and it seemed to all work as expected.

Comment: Yes. CoreDispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated event: Fired when an accelerator key is activated (pressed or held down). I want to point out that CoreAcceleratorKeys.AcceleratorKeyActivated is the identical event if you come across it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about WinRT but in WPF, you can catch routed events from all child controls by adding a handler like this.

```
this.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnKeyDown), true);
```

Where this is parent control. It could work for WinRT too, please try

**EDIT**

replace `UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent` with `UIElement.KeyDownEvent` if `UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent` doesn't exists in WinRT

Answer (score 0):

I did not answered earlier because the system did not allow me to make it because I did not have 10 reputation points so I had to wait 8 hours.

This is what I typed but it seems that it needs to declare something there that I do not know how to make it.

```
this.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(KeyUp), true);
```

The error message is

**Delegate Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler
Represents the method that will handle routed events.
Error:
No overload for 'KeyUp' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler.**

The function which will work as event handler has the following format:

```
private void KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I found a way to bypass my problem and I would like to share it with you just in case someone else needs it but if someone else knows a better way to make let me know.

I placed a button out of the visible area of the page and I used it's KeyUp event and I wrote code to make sure that it is always active. Below you can find my code.

```
public frmMain()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    btnKeboardCollector.Loaded += MyBoard_Loaded;
    btnKeboardCollector.LostFocus += btnKeboardCollector_LostFocus;
    btnKeboardCollector.KeyUp += KeyUpHandler;
}

void MyBoard_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // I do other initialization here

    btnKeboardCollector.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}

void btnKeboardCollector_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnKeboardCollector.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}

private void KeyUpHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a very straight forward solution to this. It always works, whether an element is focused or not.

**1st: the function**

```
private void onAcceleratorKey(object sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs e)
{
    CoreVirtualKeyStates ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetAsyncKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);

    if (ctrl == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        switch (e.VirtualKey)
        {
            case VirtualKey.F:
                // CTRL + F pressed.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd: the event**

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += onAcceleratorKey;
```